# How does Java bytecode deal with multiple platforms?

Tags: java, bytecode

For example, let's say you have a java program that simply opens a window. This will obviously result in different assembly code for different operating systems (on windows it will eventually have to call CreateWindowEx). So how does the Java bytecode (or any other similar language) represent something platform specific like this?

Comment: You need to download different JRE for different OS.

Comment: JRE takes care of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JVM is OS-dependent, byte code isn't.

This means that bytecode is a sort of "generic" language that JVM will interpret end execute according to the system it's running on.

---

**UPDATE**

As Chris Jester-Young says, my answer is not strictly correct:

> 1. The bytecode for a 100% pure Java program is indeed platform-independent. The underlying Java platform classes that such programs invoke are, of course, not.
> 2. Most of the time, the JVM will also JIT compile, not just interpret. (You can enable pure-interpretation mode, but it'll be slow!)

Comment: Not strictly correct. 1. The bytecode for a 100% pure Java program is indeed platform-independent. The _underlying Java platform classes_ that such programs invoke are, of course, not. 2. Most of the time, the JVM will also JIT compile, not just interpret. (You can enable pure-interpretation mode, but it'll be slow!)

Comment: Ah, that's true. @BackSlash, why not improve your answer with Chris's comment?

Comment: What do you mean by 100% pure java program?
Can you please give an example of a program which is doesn't produce platform independent byte code.

Your edited commented makes me feel like java byte code need not be platform independent.

Comment: @BVMR Some programs have a native code component, which is obviously platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Serenity said this:

Typically, the compiled code is the exact set of instructions the CPU requires to "execute" the program. In Java, the compiled code is an exact set of instructions for a "virtual CPU" which is required to work the same on every physical machine.

So, in a sense, the designers of the Java language decided that the language and the compiled code was going to be platform independent, but since the code eventually has to run on a physical platform, they opted to put all the platform dependent code in the JVM.

This requirement for a JVM is in contrast to your Turbo C example. With Turbo C, the compiler will produce platform dependent code, and there is no need for a JVM work-alike because the compiled Turbo C program can be executed by the CPU directly.

With Java, the CPU executes the JVM, which is platform dependent. This running JVM then executes the Java bytecode which is platform independent, provided that you have a JVM availble for it to execute upon. You might say that writing Java code, you don't program for the code to be executed on the physical machine, you write the code to be executed on the Java Virtual Machine.

The only way that all this Java bytecode works on all Java virtual machines is that a rather strict standard has been written for how Java virtual machines work. This means that no matter what physical platform you are using, the part where the Java bytecode interfaces with the JVM is guaranteed to work only one way. Since all the JVMs work exactly the same, the same code works exactly the same everywhere without recompiling. If you can't pass the tests to make sure it's the same, you're not allowed to call your virtual machine a "Java virtual machine".

Of course, there are ways that you can break the portability of a Java program. You could write a program that looks for files only found on one operating system (cmd.exe for example). You could use JNI, which effectively allows you to put compiled C or C++ code into a class. You could use conventions that only work for a certain operating system (like assuming ":" separates directories). But you are guaranteed to never have to recompile your program for a different machine unless you're doing something really special (like JNI).

Source: [How is Java platform-independent when it needs a JVM to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748910/how-is-java-platform-independent-when-it-needs-jvm-to-run)

Comment: In future, there is no need to copy text from another answer. Please just link to the original answer in a comment on the question (since you have the [comment anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege. Many thanks :-)

Comment: OK, sorry. I'll do so in future.

Answer (score 1):

> In the Java programming language, all source code is first written in plain text files ending with the .java extension. Those source files are then compiled into .class files by the javac compiler. A .class file does not contain code that is native to your processor; it instead contains bytecodes — the machine language of the Java Virtual Machine1 (Java VM). The java launcher tool then runs your application with an instance of the Java Virtual Machine.

[image]

[please read this doc by oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html)

`.class files`(`i.e byte code`) are same but not the `JVM` ,It differs with OS.

Answer (score 1):

There are **different Java Virtual Machine binaries** for each operating system. They can run the same Java bytecode (classes, jars), but the implementations is sometimes different.

For example, all the window handling code is implemented differently on Windows, Unix and Mac. Each of them will call the **OS native calls** to open a window or to draw something. You don't have to care about it, because the Virtual Machine automatically does it.