# Why is Java called Platform independent when its needs JVM to be installed on every machine on which it will be running?

Tags: java

It is said that Java has advantage over other languages by being platform independent.  But doesn't it makes it dependent as it relies on its JVM for the byte codes to run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Java Platform independent when it needs JVM to run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748910/how-is-java-platform-independent-when-it-needs-jvm-to-run)

Comment: I don't think this is really opinion-based. The facts are quite clear. This should have been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Duncan The facts may be clear, but their *interpretation* as to whether they constitute platform independence is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I disagree. I think with regards to Java, there is only one way to describe why it is considered by some to be platform independent. Now, the broader question of "What is platform independence?" is opinion-based. As would be the question "Should Java be considered platform independent?"

Comment: @Duncan I think OP's question is precisely about the broader topic you describe.

Answer (score 6):

Java is not platform independent. But Java code is.

`Write and Compile Java code once, it will run everywhere` whereas this is not possible in every language like `C`. And thus your java code becomes platform independent.

Comment: actually even the compiled java code will run on every machine that has java installed

Comment: You can write C/C++ code once and have it compiled and run on any platform.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik but you may need platform-specific constructs in your C/C++ which isn't the case in Java (unless, yes, you want your buttons to do something different on Windows but that's everyone's freedom).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, but you need to compile it again. Byte code will not works on other machine. Whereas Java's compiled classes runs every where.

Comment: Let me paraphrase your own answer: `Write C code once, it will compile and run on each and every machine`.

Comment: And with Java, it's `Write Java code once, install Java runtime on each and every machine, and it will run, provided that you have installed the appropriate version`. It's not that different.

Comment: You should have said something like "*Compile Java code once and it will run on every machine that has a compatible JVM installed*". Then it would distinguish Java from C.

Answer (score 5):

Platform independent in this respect means that
a) VMs are available for all major platforms
b) binaries (Java byte code) can be run on all VMs across platforms without recompilation