# How can I make my executable JAR not need JDK to run

Tags: java

I created a program in Java 1.8 using eclipse, then I exported it into an executable JAR file and it runs fine on my computer, but if I try too run it on a different computer it tells me I need to install a JDK to run it(also something about command line tools). Is there any way to make eclipse export an executable jar that doesn't require a JDK to run

Comment: JARs need a JRE, not a JDK.  What command are you running, and what error do you get?

Comment: I am running an executable jar file, on a mac, and the error is: To use the "java -jar AI_Eclipse.jar" command line tool you need to install a JDK

Comment: Googling it, it sounds like that error is just wrong; a JRE should be fine.

Comment: I know it makes no sense but it isn't working all the same

Comment: The Mac has java installed

Comment: I found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42ro3PZTwUo and it is a very similar error

Comment: Does the solution in that link work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Check Answer from this question

[How is Java platform-independent when it needs a JVM to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748910/how-is-java-platform-independent-when-it-needs-a-jvm-to-run)

You will need JRE on target environment to run your program.

Comment: I can't find anything useful in here

Comment: In short you need a JRE which is Java Runtime Environment. Executable jars dont behave like EXE files. Executable jars are run by Java Virtual Machine which is part of JRE whereas Executable files are machine level instructions. 

http://www.javabeat.net/what-is-the-difference-between-jrejvm-and-jdk/